# Why email layout is different in yahoo and gmail

Tags: php, cakephp, html-email

I have a cakephp Shell programme that send email to users but my in Yahoo email is fine but in gmail it looks bad.

Any help?

Thanks[image: Yahoo Image![][1]]

[image: Gmail Image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the exact same email in both clients? The way that gmail is rendering the table it looks like you have a closing tag issue somewhere around the "Close Task" column.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/9c8c48201f7a71ea70d8

Comment: This is my gist code.All tags are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of css rules supported varies greatly for different email clients. So to ensure consistent display you should use only those rules that are supported by all (or most) clients. You can check the list of css rules supported for popular emails client here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Table layout is supported by all emails clients according https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ then why in gmail table look different?

Comment: Well it's not just about using tables. Did you not see the whole list of individual css properties listed there? Have you used anyone of them that is not supported by gmail?

Comment: From that list i am using only table and it is supported in both gmail and yahoo